# My Sub Domains pointing to Main Domain in Google cloud windows VM

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis, subdomain, google-cloud-platform

Below are the things i have done so far

1. I have a domain from hostingraja.in say domain.in  and set up a windows vm on google cloud platform with static IP address.
2. In google console, DNS zone is created , name servers generated , Created a new record to point the domain to an external IP address.
3. In my domain provider I updated the domain name servers  to use cloud DNS.
4. In IIS a default website is created with  simple index.html  page with contnet "Main Domain". So When I access domain.in it displays "Main Domain"
   So far everything went well and I am able to access domain.in from browser.Now I want to set up a sub domain
5. In Google DNS created "A" record with name sb.domain.in and piointed to VM IP.
6. In IIS I created another virtual directory with name sb.domain, with an index.html  having content "My Sub Domain" and updated the bindings.

Issue: When I browse sb.domain.in, the browser displays "Main Domain" instead of "My Sub Domain"

The question :

1.How to point this sb.domain.in to my virtual directory sb.domain so that when browsed it should display My Sub Domain

I watched many you tube videos for last 1 week and played with windows DNS manager(Forwarding look up zones/reverse look up zones etc) and ehternet settings as mentioned in the blogs/videos but finally lost RDP access to the VM(I need to set up anoher vm now)

2. What exactly needs to be done in Windows DNS manager and ethernet settings(if any) to set up multiple sub domains pointing to separate virtual directories.s

Comment: Step 6 is completely wrong. Sub-domains should be separate web sites (bind with different host names to match the sub-domains).

Answer (score 1):

> How to point this sb.domain.in to my virtual directory sb.domain

You just need the (A) record and the correct IIS binding ("Hostname"). There isn't anything else.

> so that when browsed it should display My Sub Domain

That should be the case even if called from localhost. Just RDP into you machine, check the dns record ("ping" should answer your public ip address) and open your browser. If the *incorrect* site is displayed, your IIS bindungs are *not* correct.

In this case I would bind the Default Page to the public IP (port 80, *) and the subdomain to the IP (port 80, hostname subdomain.domain.in). Double-check the binding/directory configuration. The second site MUST have an OWN directory, it cannot reside in the same folder.

> played with windows DNS manager(Forwarding look up zones/reverse look up zones etc) and ehternet settings ....

Stop that.

A browser first resolves the ip of you server and then sends a request to this IP which contains the [vhost name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header) (subdomain, hostname).

Comment: Read step 6 in the question. He/she created a virtual directory, which is why everything fails.

Comment: Virtual directories within sites do not have their own bindings. That's why I wrote "site" multiple times.